# Save data from multiple screens to submit using powerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, powerapp

How can I save data from fields across multiple screens to submit as one entry?

For example, I can use an Edit Screen to submit a form with 25 fields. I'd rather have a flow with detailed explanations so each field (or two) is on separate screens. I can create a button to the next screen, but how do I save the data from each field/screen and submit all fields at once? Or (and on a related note), if I have to submit each field at at time, how do I append the data to the same record?

Comment: I know its been long time, but have you resolved this Issue, cause I am facing the same, Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-variables#types-of-variables), you can create a global variable using the Set function. These will persist between screens which allows you to accumulate them and submit all at once. You could also use a collection, which gives you the same basic capabilities, but in table form.